# Value into href to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

my blade looks like this...

```
@if(count($alleSpiele) > 0)
        <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)
            <a href='spielerAuswahl' class="list-group-item">{{$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}</a>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
@endif
```

This is my route...

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl', 'SpielplanController@getHeimGast');
```

Here is my controller...

```
public function getHeimGast(){
    return view('test');
}
```

Now, my problem is to take the choosen variable from a href heimmannschaft from blade to route into the controller? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: what value you want to take??

Comment: Why not read a [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing)?

Comment: Value is Heimmannschaft. I can't find a manual for this.

Comment: I provided you a link, follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your links to this

```
<a href='spielerAuswahl/{{$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}' class="list-group-item">{{$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}</a>
```

then change your route to

```
Route::get('/spielerAuswahl/{value}', 'SpielplanController@getHeimGast');
```

then in the controller you can have the variable like this:

```
public function getHeimGast($value){
// use $value in your code
    return view('test');
}
```